# Get highest number from table cell content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the highest number (8 in example below) from the table cells with specific class.  I'm assuming I'll have to convert it to an array and then do math.max on it?

This is my HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is really what I've tried, but it just returns 384.  So math.max doesn't work on it.

```
var varID = $('.id').text();
var varArray= jQuery.makeArray(varID);
alert (varArray);
```

Comment: It is working the maximum in an array containing 384 is 384! What you want is to loop through those td's that have a ‘class='id'‘ and find the maximum that way...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the best way would be:

```
var max = 0;
$('.id').each(function()
{
   $this = parseInt( $(this).text() );
   if ($this > max) max = $this;
});
alert(max);
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hfkSp/2/)

Comment: You should be selecting on `.id` to use avoid sizzle, and you should be caching `$(this).text()`. Other than that, this is good logic. +1

Comment: you could also use a ternary operator in this case. `max = $(this).text > max ? $(this).text : max;`

Comment: @ahren your ternary is more verbose than @Sam's breakless, braceless `if` :)

Comment: `parseInt` is actually redundant here thanks to JS's loosely-typed numeric comparison logic.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Thanks for the heads up, I wasn't sure if this was an issue or not, so I added it in incase it caused the OP any problems

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
var high = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.id').map(function(){
         return $(this).text()
}))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9mQwT/

Comment: Wow I like this method a lot.

Comment: Is this cross browser compatible?

Comment: Hmm, it works in IE9, but I don't have a way to test in true IE6-8.   It craps out in IE6-8 in IETester.  I'll change my answer if it doesn't appear to be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: On IE8 I get this error : SCRIPT5028: Function.prototype.apply: Array or arguments object expected 
_display, line 20 character 1

Comment: Yea I was getting something similar in IETester.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I'll change my answer to yours since it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Check this  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C8wJn/)

```
$(function() {

   // Get all the elements with class id
   var $td = $('table .id');
   var max = 0;
    $.each($td , function(){
        if( parseInt($(this).text()) > max){
           max = parseInt($(this).text())
        }
    });
            console.log('Max number is : ' + max)

});​
```

You can use parseInt or parseFloat to convert it to a number otherwise , it will compare them like strings with their ascii values..

Comment: AFAIK using `parseInt` it's always good to represent a radix parameter: `parseInt($(this).text(), 10)` +1 anyway